# Understand SSH AgentForwarding per Host specification

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

**Disclaimer**: originally I asked this question on StackOverflow and it was legitimately marked off-topic and think it fits better here. In the meantime I **found the problem** (see intermediate solution below).

## Original problem

I am on a Windows client and want to connect via SSH to an Ubuntu Client.

my configuration (which is **working**) looks like this:

```
Host myhost
  ForwardAgent Yes

Host myuser@myhost
  HostName myhost
  User myuser
```

I can connect, fowarding works as expected, so that `ssh-add -l` on the remote shows the identity from my connecting client.

Now, what I do not understand is, why the following configuration does **not work**:

```
Host myuser@myhost
  ForwardAgent Yes
  HostName myhost
  User myuser
```

In that case I can at least connect through SSH, but the forwarding does not work, so that running `ssh-add -l` again returns:

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

To me the second configuration looks basically the same but in one step rather in two.

<s>What am I missing here?</s>

## What I tried

[One suggestion that I got](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78147473/6453106) was to replace the `@` sign with another. This unfortunately it was not working.

Then I made some minor changes like lowercase `yes` for example. Nothing changed.

## intermediate solution

After really just trying in *try and error*-style. I found that the first `Host` naming style was OK:

```
Host myhost
    HostName myhost
    User myuser
    ForwardAgent yes
```

And it turns out, that I can change the `Host` as I was **but** I must not include the name from `User` ? This turns out as a pattern.

## Questions

- Does someone understand why the `User` is not allowed?
- what is the best practice when I want to include another specification but with another user? My first configuration followed that intention, see:

```
Host user1@myhost
    HostName myhost
    User user1
    ForwardAgent yes

Host user2@myhost
    HostName myhost
    User user2
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Which would not work.

Also not working:

```
Host myuser-myhost
    HostName myhost
    User myuser
    ForwardAgent yes
```

or

```
Host myhost-myuser
    HostName myhost
    User myuser
    ForwardAgent yes
```

or

```
Host myhostmyuser
    HostName myhost
    User myuser
    ForwardAgent yes


Host myusermyhost
    HostName myhost
    User myuser
    ForwardAgent yes
```

not even

```
Host mymyuserhost
    HostName myhost
    User myuser
    ForwardAgent yes
```

really confused. How do I distinct two configurations with two different users then? Only by having two different files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Host` is supposed to match a hostname given as a command line argument to `ssh`, like `ssh host`. It can be a pattern with wildcards like `*` or `?`. It doesn't include a username. When you connect with a command like `ssh user1@myhost` then this argument is split into a username `user1` and a hostname `myhost` and the hostname would match against `Host` directives. As the symbol `@` isn't a wildcard then your `Host user1@myhost` would never match `myhost`.

If you want the configuration to apply to a specific user only then you need to use the `Match` directive instead of `Host`, like the following:

```
Match host myhost user user1
```

See [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Afterall, I still was a little confused why there would be an option to define `User` as well. From the docs: *`User` [...] saves the trouble of having to remember to give the user name on the command line.* So the `User` is for the lazy people of us and `Match` is for the restrictive people of us :D Thank you very much @AlexD